# Locating figure in the center of a page

Tags: elsarticle, page

I use "elsarticle" class and for locating a figure (PDF file) in the center of the page, I use the following code:

```
\begin{figure}\label{Fig:7}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=17cm,height=20cm,keepaspectratio]{Figs/f}}
\caption{Caption.} 
\end{figure}
```

But, unfortunately the figure is not placed in the center and inclines to the right side of the page. Specifically, when the size of the image increases, some part of it becomes hidden in the right side of the page. This is a solution from one of the previous posts but it does not work for me. How it can be corrected?

**Update**
The solution @Mico suggested produces the following result.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: In `figure` and `table` environments, *always* place `\label` after, not before, `\caption`.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\includegraphics[width=17cm,height=20cm,keepaspectratio]{Figs/f}` with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figs/f}`?

Comment: @Mico , Thanks for the solution, but I can't control height and width appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't control height and width appropriately"?

Comment: @Mico , Changing values for them has no effect on the size of figure. Also, setting higher values shifts the figure to the right and pushes it out of the page.

Comment: That's normal, if the chosen width is greater than elsarticle text width.

Comment: So the real problem is the insane amount of whitespace padding contained in the graphic. You may want to inquire about how to go about removing the whitespace padding.

Answer (score 2):

If the `elsarticle` class is loaded with any options, the default width of the text block is 345pt=12.125cm. Insisting on setting `width=17cm` will get you nothing but a graphic that's 4.875cm too wide. Don't believe me? Consult the log file, where you'll find a warning that some \hbox is `138.69684pt` too wide. A quick calculation verifies that `138.69684pt=4.875cm`.

What to do? Do just what I already suggested in a comment, i.e., replace

```
\includegraphics[width=17cm,height=20cm,keepaspectratio]{Figs/f}
```

with

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.95\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figs/f}
```

Why `height=0.95\textheight` rather than, say, `height=1\textheight`? It's because you need to reserve some space for the caption.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[demo]{elsarticle} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
                 height=0.95\textheight, % leave space for caption
                 keepaspectratio]%
                {Figs/f}
\caption{Caption.}  
\label{Fig:7x} % always place \label after, not before, \caption
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated the OP, but I'm looking for a way to enlarge the figure.

Comment: @Rwy5 - The screenshot you show in the addendum to your query indicates strongly that the real problem is with the image file. More specifically, it seems to contain an unbelievable amount of whitespace padding. The *real* fix is to edit the graphic file to get rid of the needless whitespace.

Comment: Padding for this image is as its minimum possible rate. This is why I couldn't realize the problem.

Comment: @Rwy5 - If the graphics software you employ insists on inserting an imbecillic amount of whitespace padding, the solution is to switch to saner software.